# How I handle the swig and markdown

Tags: html, node.js, express, markdown, swig-template

I was using Express and swig to do my project. I want to add the "markdown" to my project editer. But there is some conflict happened.

For example: in the views, I use `{{ title }}` in the index.html. In fact, the `title` is `<h2>www</h2>`， what I want to see is that-"In the browser, the `www` with h2 will be output", but In the browser, the page was output by `<h2>www</h2>`.

What should I do in the Express? I make a test which is add code `app.set('view autoescape', false);` in the app.js, but nothing is change! What should I do?

Comment: Try to use 3 curly braces like this: `{{{ title }}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deactivate autoescaping for a certain value by declaring it:

```
{% autoescape false %}{{ title }}{% endautoescape %}
```

Another solution is setting it as default:

```
swig.setDefaults({ autoescape: false });
```

Comment: Yes! I soloved the problem with your ways. Besides, is there an easier way? such as `app.set('view autoescape', false)`

Comment: I'm cannot guarantee, but it should work with `swig.setDefaults({ autoescape: false });`

Comment: Yes! I add it in app.js. Perfectly, my problem has soloved! Thsnks

Comment: Nice! If you liked my answer can you please mark it as useful?